# OmniAuth Google OpenID WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick, omniauth

I am using OmniAuth to allow users to log in with their Google OpenID accounts. When I try to log in in development mode with WEBrick, I get a WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge error. When I deploy it to my rails host, it works fine.
Is there a different web server I should use instead of WEBrick?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Strange, I wonder what the URI length limit is for WEBrick. You could try `thin` http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/. I use this locally for development sometimes and it seems to work great.

Comment: I have to admit, the URL is quite long... It contains a lot in the query string

Comment: I would file a bug with OmniAuth or see if they provide a solution that doesn't use a query string.

Comment: Definitely a webrick limitation.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in railscast 236 for OmniAuth, WEBrick has trouble with long urls given by OpenID.  The solution given that worked for me was to add Mongrel to your gemfile.

> gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'

Answer (score 7):

Add a file called `webrick.rb` file to the `config\initializers` directory.

```
if defined?(WEBrick::HTTPRequest)
  WEBrick::HTTPRequest.const_set("MAX_URI_LENGTH", 10240)
end
```

Comment: This is the best solution for me because it actually works with webrick.

Answer (score 3):

The url size limit changed from 1024 to 2083 in the latest ruby source already. I hope an updated ruby version with this fix included will be released soon :)

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/webrick/httprequest.rb#L291

Comment: Usually Webrick is used for debugging so a small monkey-patch will not harm you ;)

Comment: Yeah, but it's ugly and there's really no need for such a low limit...good they already fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with [Caseproof's DataTables gem](https://github.com/Caseproof/datatables) using Webbrick and a table that had a lot of columns  (> 15). Switching to the thin server resolved my issue as well. [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) is a javascript/jquery plugin for creating tables.