# WEBrick: RequestURITooLarge: should I update or use a different server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, webrick

I currently have:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.9 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-11-30 13:18:00] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-11-30 13:18:00] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2011-11-30 13:18:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4204 port=3000
```

The problem I'm having is I'm using openID for auth and getting the following error:

```
[2011-11-30 13:18:19] ERROR WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge
```

In the browser:

```
Request-URI Too Large
WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-02-18) at macbook-pro.local:3000
```

How can I fix this? Can I update WEBrick or do I really need to use a different web server?

Thanks

Comment: I tried Unicorn but get: You have already activated rack 1.3.3, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.4. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Need to add this is a localhost issue. I'm trying to get this bug fixed locally only at the moment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.3. source, it says that MAX_URI_LENGTH = 2083. That means that the latest version of Webrick can't handle urls longer that this. And that's what the WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge exception is telling you.

The solution therefore is to use a different web server. One of the most favourite ones is Thin:

```
sudo gem install thin

cd to/your/rails/app

thin -h

thin -a localhost start
```

Comment: When I try thing I get an error: /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.3.3, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.4. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: ok figured that out. Does thing not show rails logging like webrick?

Comment: Wait this is for local... Are you saying I should use thing for local?

Comment: Actually, I would run it use `bundle exec rails s thin`.  This will run the rails server using thin as the web server.

Comment: If you are using `rvm` to install `thin`. Just use `gem install thin`.

Answer (score 6):

Like [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261476/535203), you could change the `MAX_URI_LENGTH` using this code:

```ruby
WEBrick::HTTPRequest.const_set("MAX_URI_LENGTH", 10240)
```

Comment: Adding this to the ApplicationController seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've tried unicorn: have you tried running it through bundler? Add:

```
gem :unicorn
```

to your `Gemfile` and run:

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails
```

to start the server and browse to http://localhost:8080.

Comment: running bundle exec rails s loads Booting WEBrick

Comment: Oops: you're right. You need to run `bundle exec unicorn_rails` in the root. Updated the answer.