# Request-URI Too Large in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 running environments of same rails app. one is development and second one is say staging. when i try to run my app on development environment then it runs good without any exception. but when i try to run same app on staging, then it throws an exception of Request-URI too large error. i run this app using webrick on both development and staging.

Comment: Why not use thin? People say Webrick isn't supposed to be run in production. `gem 'thin'` and to start it `rails s`

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that your request uri is longer than 2083 chars. This is the max uri size of the webrick. But to replace webrick with thin will help.

```
sudo gem install thin
```

and

```
thin start
```

Answer (score 2):

Webrick can't handle URI's longer than `MAX_URI_LENGTH = 2083` ([according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333158/webrick-requesturitoolarge-should-i-update-or-use-a-different-server)). And it's not really supposed to be run in production (some people say)

Try using thin. `gem 'thin'` in your Gemfile, installing and then `rails s`