# Error RequestURITooLarge searching ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, search

Here the thing: I have multiples search fields in my form. But i got the error RequestURITooLarge when I tried to do a multiples searches...I'm wondering if it is exist a method to avoid this problem. Every time you fill the text box or date field increment the url and got the error. I also tried a reset button but just clean the text fields. Here the code for you to understand the method I use and perhaps will help you in some way. Tks!!

View_item

```
def self.search(s_codigo, s_den_cont, s_marca)
where("codigo ilike :s_c and den_cont ilike :s_d and marca ilike :s_m", s_c: "%#{s_codigo}%", s_d: "%#{s_den_cont}%", s_m: "%#{s_marca}%")
end

#Search section #2  

def self.search_fec_min(s_codigo, s_den_cont, s_marca, s_fec_min)
where("codigo ilike :s_c and den_cont ilike :s_d and marca ilike :s_m and date_expired >= :s_fmin", s_c: "%#{s_codigo}%", s_d: "%#{s_den_cont}%", s_m: "%#{s_marca}%", s_fmin: "#{s_fec_min}")
end
```

index

```
<%= text_field_tag :s_codigo, params[:s_codigo], placeholder: "Search for cod" %>
<%= text_field_tag :s_den_cont, params[:s_den_cont], placeholder: "Search for Denominación" %>
<%= text_field_tag :s_marca, params[:s_marca], placeholder: "Search brand" %>
<%= date_select :s_fec_min, params[:s_fec_min], placeholder: "Search for date", :include_blank => true %>
```

Controller

```
if self.is_date(params[:s_fec_min])
@items = View_item.all.order("date_expired ASC").page(params[:page]).per(15).search_fec_min(params[:s_codigo], params[:s_den_cont], params[:s_marca], params[:s_fec_min])     
  elsif (params[:s_codigo] != "" or params[:s_den_cont] != "" or params[:s_marca] != "")
@items = View_item.all.order("date_expired ASC").page(params[:page]).per(15).search(params[:s_codigo], params[:s_den_cont], params[:s_marca])
  else
@items = View_item.all.order("date_expired ASC").page(params[:page]).per(15)
end
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602028/request-uri-too-large-in-rails

Comment: Tks Yev.. seams to be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MAX_URI_LENGTH is set to only 2083 characters for webrick server. On accessing url of length more than this limit throws WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge exception.**

Try to switch to different server :

```
#Gemfile
gem 'thin'

$bundle install 
$ rails s

=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```