# Edit Action rendering blank page; Parameters hash is displayed in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, associations

I am working on an application where one controller controls the create action of several models. I have a lot more code, but I'm not sure if this error is specific to code or a generic fix (like changing the HTTP request) that doesn't require me to post my entire set up.

I have a 'basketball' model that **belongs_to** 'activities' that is generated from the **activities controller**. Each activity **has_one** basketball model.

Then in the basketballs controller I have this.

```
def edit
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  @basketball = @activity.basketball
 end

def update
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  @basketball = @activity.basketball
  if @basketball.update_attributes(basketball_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Activity has been updated."
    redirect_to activities_path
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Activity has not been updated."
    render 'edit'
  end
```

end

However, when I click the update button, my page renders a blank page with all of the parameters in the url. Example:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/basketballs/10/edit?utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=patch&authenticity_token=[token]&basketball
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It seems that the edit form method is `GET`. what do your logs look like?

Comment: Oh, I was using unicorn which isn't very descriptive. Webrick now says the request is too large.

Request-URI Too Large

WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: The form is huge. 

I'm going to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926740/omniauth-google-openid-webrickhttpstatusrequesturitoolarge

Comment: Ok, I used thin and now it says 'Bad Request.' The form is too large to post. I can create a gist, do you need the actual form or the params only?

Comment: a gist is perfect. The actual form and the query please (using WEBrick for now)

Comment: The issue was/is GET request size. I counted the characters in the URL and it summed to 13,672. So I added this method:

if defined?(WEBrick::HTTPRequest)
  WEBrick::HTTPRequest.const_set("MAX_URI_LENGTH", 20240)
end

to an initializer. that permits the string but no update yet. but no error.

Comment: It doesn't explain why the params are displayed in the URL though. Still interested in the gists

Comment: https://gist.github.com/miler350/6501431

Comment: Let me know if you need anymore code. Thanks!

Comment: Ouch, really massive indeed ;) But I didn't find anything wrong... May I see the log please? I want to check the form method, the params and the action called + any exceptions

Comment: https://gist.github.com/miler350/6501980

The log actually renders the edited params now btw. I increased the Webrick limit to 20,000. However, the create action doesn't work still and I don't think that's fix anyway because I don't use Webrick in production.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to update or create the resource? The only logs I saw were for the GET edit action.

Comment: I want to update the resource.

Comment: Show me the **PUT/PATCH update** log. I only got the GET edit log please

Comment: How do you do that? Sorry for ignorance.

Comment: Just clcik the submit button of your form and copy the output from the terminal. It should start with Started PATCH or something like that.

Comment: oh, like the line i posted in the original?

https://gist.github.com/miler350/6502243#file-gistfile1-txt-L1

this is hard to read.

Comment: This gist https://gist.github.com/miler350/6501980 is what you get when you try to **update** a resource? But it is a GET request to the edit action, not a,put/patch to the update action. I m confuse

Comment: https://gist.github.com/miler350/6502243#file-gistfile1-txt-L1

no this. this is the URL and my patch request.

Comment: The update action is specified in your routes file? Post routes

Comment: The routes file doesn't have any magic.

https://gist.github.com/miler350/6502392

Comment: Thats really weird. Do you have an open source version I can check?

Comment: https://github.com/miler350/corehero

Comment: @miler350 These updates should be in your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 nested forms in your views.

Here are the problems: [app/views/strengthworkouts/_formatting.html.erb line 65](https://github.com/miler350/corehero/blob/master/app/views/strengthworkouts/_formatting.html.erb#L65) and [app/views/workouts/_strengthworkout.html.erb line 5](https://github.com/miler350/corehero/blob/master/app/views/workouts/_strengthworkout.html.erb#L5)

**Remove those `<form>` tags, keep the `form_for`.**

**Only the outermost form was used.** And because it doesn't have any `action` or `method` or whatsoever attribute, submitting it just triggers a `GET` to the current path with the params in the query string.