# Rails active resource: how to send post parameters in the request body and not as query strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, activeresource

I am calling some post request using rails activeresource, however all the parameters are sent as query string and the result is that the called url is too long and I get `WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge` exception.

So I need to send the parameters in the request body instead, however I couldn't find how to do this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post request data is sent in the request body already.  Are you definitely doing a POST request? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To send a post request in activeresource you should reference [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/activeresource/ActiveResource/CustomMethods#post-instance_method)

For example you can do this

```
#Entity.post(custom_method_name, options = {}, body = '')
Company.post(:add_role, nil, {user_id: 1, role_id: 2}.to_json)
```

Tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: No problem my friend. Rabena ma3ak

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you are doing the post request within a link. Anchor by default will create the query parameter. But if you use button and that does send the data by default in post method send as request body like a form of post method. Please try out the following the code snippets:

```
button_to 'Your post requesting link name', something_path(:your_params => :will be here)
```

Let me know if this works!

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install [thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/) server instead of Webrick, read these [answer-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333603/2791480), [answer-2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929815/2791480).

Or, Add `webrick.rb` file to `config\initializers` directory, and add the following code:

```
if defined?(WEBrick::HTTPRequest)
  WEBrick::HTTPRequest.const_set("MAX_URI_LENGTH", 10240)
end
```

Read also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261476/2791480).

Comment: The question is mostly about sending parameters as a request body then query string. Configuring the server to allow or increase the size of the uri shouldn't be the solution in so many cases I guess.